# How could I make a 1kW fan heater consume less electricity?

Tags: voltage, mains, heat, diy, electricity

My fan heater has only two settings, 1kW and 2kW. 
But what if I wanted it to consume only 200W per hour ? Could I find a device to put in between to supply less electricity, how would I do that?

Comment: You buy a 200W heater.

Comment: There is no such thing as "200 W per hour". You want 200 W. If you use a dimmer which can handle the motor load of your fan inside it and dim it to 20% or 200 W, you might end up in a situation where the fan stops running but your heating element still gives off heat, although much less than before.

Comment: Switch it on for 1/5th of the time. Possibly with a timer (contact making clock).

Comment: Run it at 2000W for 1 minute, then turn it off for 10 minutes.  The average power will be 200W.

Comment: "200 W per hour" means nothing, you mean you want it to consume 200 W instead of 1 kW or 2 kW so that it consumes not 1 kWHr or 2 kWHr but 200 WattHour. What you do is duty cycle it on 1 kW setting: 1 minute on, 4 minutes off giving 1/5 of average power = 1 kW /5 = 200 W.

Comment: If you are concerned about peak power (you are blowing breakers) there is no easy way. If average (electricity cost) is your concern, run it less or set the thermostat down.

Comment: "200W per hour" makes no sense.  -1 for gross sloppiness with units.

Comment: Is your "fan heater" an AC unit? If so, what voltage and frequency (cycles - 50 or 60)? Yes, there is a way to do this if it is AC. But you will probably have to rewire the unit to separate the fan from the heater. Tell me more about the unit, perhaps provide a link to a data sheet, photo, or link to similar unit.

Comment: @JRE: Run it at 2000W for 1 minute, then turn it off for 10 minutes. The average power will be 182 W. For 200 W, it should be turned off for 9 minutes, the resulting cycle time will be 10 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

As has been covered in the other answers, you have your units confused. If you want to reduce the heat output from your heater to an average of 200 W, you need to pulse-width modulate the standard 1000 W output setting. To do this, you need a time-switch. On for 20 minutes, off for 80 - repeat. Finding a time-switch that allows you to set enough on-off times at the right precision might be hard - a temperature based approach might be simpler.

This will not reduce the peak power draw, or how hot the heater might get (to a first approximation). Switching like this will increase the chance that the heater fails sooner, maybe not by very much.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in what you said: the fan heater **power** is either 1 kW or 2 kW, but when you say that you want it to consume only 200 W per hour you're talking about **energy**, which is just \$power \times time\$. 
Thus, your fan heater consumes either 1 kWh or 2 kWh, depending on the setting, (as pointed out by user *FakeMoustache* in the comments) and you would like it to have a 200 W power (thus reducing its energy consumption and the heat it gives you).

Then, anyway, the answer to your question is no, you can't put anything in between, if by "in between" you mean between the mains plug and your device. What you would have to do is to open your fan heater and modify its internal circuitry, those modifications depending on the fan heater you have.

Answer (score -5):

Yes, you go to hardware store, electrical department, and buy a 1200W [dimmer](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Eaton-Devine-1200-Watt-Dimmable-LED-FLR-Dimmer-with-Presets-Color-Kit-DF10P-C5/206469431).

REWORK SUGGESTION: you will need to open up the AC cord, identify hot wire, and install (wire-up) the dimmer in accord with dimmer instructions. Then wrap the whole thing up by duct tape, in best DIY traditions. Do not use 2kW configuration.

Comment: this will run the fan slow as well, which may be too slow, as in stalled.

Comment: Also, it's a 2000W heater, so the 1200W dimmer will fail.

Comment: Non-issue, folks. The device has a 1kW configuration, I assume it is not by active dimmer. To drop 1000W to 200W, the voltage needs to be only at about half level, so the fan will likely be fine. If not, connect the fan directly to AC, and use the dimmer on heater only.